# Assertion that value is set in map in java and testng or junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, http-headers, testng

I have a test written in java which contains a simple HTTP request sent to the server and then capture the server response.

Here I want a way to assert the console output of the response header that I am receiving from the server?

Example on one of the response header: if "Content-Length" = 12227 then its a pass or else it fails that test.

Here is my code:

```
public class ResponseHeaderLoggedInUser {

@Test
public void ResponseHeadersforUSA() {

    try {


        //System.setOut(myconsole);
        URL obj = new URL("http://www.ivivva.com/?locale=en_US");
        URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();


        //Setting Request Headers//
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.ivivva.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "NSC_JOv4n55lbq2w4zpexoskqbexxcrzicc=ffffffff09d205ab45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; UsrLocale=en_US; Country=US; ca_ord=gGYBmQjaBCVj65TJ+vOBJw==; isLoggedin=true; cartCount=0; NSC_mvmvmfnpo_tubhfw10_jwjwwb_mc=ffffffff09d205ab45525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0; omniID=1482345027850BoER; mbox=session#1482345027884-6794#1482347607|check#true#1482345807; __utma=210616138.1023825236.1482345028.1482345028.1482345028.1; __utmb=210616138.5.10.1482345028; __utmc=210616138; __utmz=210616138.1482345028.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); s_cc=true; s_fid=752E92B2B20003FF-05DED4FECDE6B525; c_m2=1; c_m=undefinedDirect%20LoadDirect%20Load; s_nr=1482345746223; s_vnum=1484937028265%26vn%3D1; s_invisit=true; s_lv=1482345746225; s_lv_s=First%20Visit; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; sandy-session-id=0fa3f19b82e69e2a; sandy-client-id=93c64748da80825e; BTT_X0siD=807679838813198396; BTT_Collect=on; s_vi=[CS]v1|2C2D6522051D272B-6000016360010F9A[CE]; _ga=GA1.2.1023825236.1482345028; sl=CA; BTT_WCD_Collect=off; JSESSIONID=61AE25BF6E33856CB6FDD67DC939D9B6; regionMsgShown=true; us_ord=27qFcsniy0Bv/8EVzdZzNw==; _gat_mobifyTracker=1; __utmt_ga=1");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");


        Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

        System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");

        System.out.println("This test is for Logged in user with userlocale present\n");



        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey()
                    + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());


        }

         } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }}
```

Comment: What's the question you have?

Comment: I have now added a "?" to my sentence above. please take a look.

Comment: maybe something like assertEquals("12227",map.get("Content-Length"))?

Comment: Consider using a library like `okhttp` which gives you easier access to the response headers

Comment: Thanks BrianPipa - It worked! it should be conn.getHeaderField instead of map.get, I was getting some unexpected results with map.get, then I tried with conn.getHeaderField > it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Thanks larsgrefer - I will give it a try soon!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using JUnit Test cases here. If you know how to retrieve the value of Content-Length, you can use the AssertEquals functionality, which takes the two parameters that you'd like to compare.

In the JUnit, your code would look something like this:

```
AssertEquals("Expected Value","Actual Value");
```

Thus, for your Content-Length:

```
AssertEquals("12227", map.get(Content-Length));
```

The only thing you need to be able to do is to retrieve the actual content-length correctly.